# C++ for-each statement triggers "vector iterators incompatible" assertion failure: this->_Getcont() == 0

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

This is with Visual Studio 2012.

```
static void func(
  ...,
  const std::vector<std::string> &opt_extra_args_strs,
  ...)
{
   // THIS ASSERTS: "vector iterators incompatible"
   for (const std::string &arg_str : opt_extra_args_strs) {
      ... body does not modify opt_extra_args_strs

   // BUT THIS WORKS:
   for (size_t a_ix = 0; a_ix < opt_extra_args_strs.size(); a_ix++) {
       const std::string &arg_str = opt_extra_args_strs[a_ix];
}
```

I am not modifying the vector at all in the loop body, and in fact, the assertion happens before the first iteration. The vector looks right in the debugger, but I don't know enough about STL to look for corruption. Inside the STL the assertion failure comes from:

```
void _Compat(const _Myiter& _Right) const {
    // test for compatible iterator pair
    if (this->_Getcont() == 0 // THIS FAILS (_Getcont() == 0)
         ...) {
        _DEBUG_ERROR("vector iterators incompatible");
```

with `this->_Getcont()` being NULL because (`_Myproxy` is NULL in the `_Iterator_base12`).
The call stack is:

```
msvcp110d.dll!std::_Debug_message(const wchar_t * message, const wchar_t * file, unsigned int line) Line 15 C++
Main.exe!std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > > >::_Compat(const std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > > > & _Right)
Main.exe!std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > > >::operator==(const std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > > > & _Right)
Main.exe!std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > > >::operator!=(const std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > > > & _Right)
Main.exe!run_test(..., const std::vector<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::allocator<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > > & opt_extra_args_strs)
    ...
```

I suspect the code setting up the vector is screwing it up somehow, but I am not sure.  I am having difficulty writing a simpler reproducer as well, but the program should be totally deterministic (single threaded, not random variables, always asserts).

Additionally, I also run into a different similar assertion failure earlier `"vector iterator + offset out of range"` with the snippet (on the same vector)

```
template <typename T>
class Elsewhere {
    virtual void earlier(
        ....
        std::vector<T> &v) const
    {
       v.emplace_back(); // empty construction of a T
      // T &t = v.back(); // assertion failure
      T &val = to[to.size() - 1]; // but this works
      ... mutates val.
```

With `T = std::string` (in fact, the same vector).

I mention this because within STL the condition for this failure ends up also being `this->_Getcont() == 0`, and I suspect them to be related.  What does it mean for `_Getcont()` to be 0 in a `Vector_const_iterator`?

The vector comes out of a container

```
template <typename T>
struct type {
   T m_value;

   operator const T &() const {
     return value();
   }

   const T &value() const {
       return m_value;
   }
};

type<std::vector<std::string>> &t = ... method call that returns ref to it;
... t gets set
func(t); // implicit conversion to (const std::vector<std::string> &)
```

Comment: `&opt_extra_args_strs`: is it a reference?

Comment: I added some calling code to illustrate where it comes from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the problem.  A path deep in the vector's setup code was clobbering the vector's state (memset'ing it to 0's as part of a larger chunk of memory).  This caused no harm for the first three fields in vector:  `_Myfirst`, `_Mylast`, and `_Myend` since those fields are 0 in an initial vector.  Moreover, most things such as the array index operator and other methods such as push_back still functioned correctly. However, the fourth field `_Myproxy` was initially non-zero, and clearing it disabled iterator-based functionality.  Hence, for-each loop, `vector::back()`, and others all fail with different false errors such as false bounds checks, false incompatible iterators, etc...

Comment: That likely means you modified the vector while you are iterating over it, which is not valid.

Comment: @BillyONeal The question states "I am not modifying the vector at all in the loop body, and in fact, the assertion happens before the first iteration." If it happens before the loop body is entered, the loop body cannot be the problem. That said, I am curious to know what could be the problem. Unlike the OP, I don't really find this answer satisfactory: "*something* is corrupting memory" is the first step to finding the answer (and a good step, I know it can be tricky to find), but the actual answer, IMO, would be finding *what* is corrupting memory, why, and what you should do to avoid it.

Comment: @hvd. I totally agree, and that's what I did to find this solution.  My question was aimed at looking for that "something" and hoping someone else had seen these symptoms.  In any case I did find the problem, and that's this answer.  If you zero the memory of a valid empty stl::vector (in a debug build, VS2012+ etc), push_back and indexing operations will still work, but iteration-based ops (foreach, and back()) will fail with non-intuitive errors (as those described).

Comment: @Tim Ah, now I see, you meant your code, which was setting up the vectors, was using memset. I thought you meant that the vector's own methods were using memset (due to an invalid call somewhere), I didn't read "the vector's setup code" the way you intended. In that case, good find, and good answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this assert failure myself.  I discovered the cause to be that something I was calling within the loop was modifying the vector that I was iterating through.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first item with the *range for* loop, unless there is something new in the C++11 standard, the incompatible iterator message is 100 percent accurate.  That line is attempting to assign a constant string reference to an iterator from the vector.  An iterator type is not compatible with the data type of the element being stored.

Please take a look at http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#for.  In that example, the auto datatype is used so that the under the hood setting of the iterator through the colon usage is set at the beginning of the container (e.g. much less keyboard typing than the old days).  Then more under the hood things occur that make sure the iterator never passes the last element.  The equivalent of the range for loop above (as written) is:

```
// added a local string to clearly indicate types
std::string s1;
const std::string &arg_str = s1;


const std::vector<std::string> :: iterator i;
i = opt_extra_args_strs.begin(); // happens inside the range for

for (arg_str = i; i < opt_extra_args_strs.end(); i++)
{
   // loop body
}
```

As soon as the arg_str reference is reassigned to the starting point for the iterator, the compiler should complain and print an error.

The second for loop is an older alternative to avoid iterators, but continue to use the other methods available for range checking a dynamic container like a vector, and stay within the container bounds for the quantity of elements currently inside it.  That loop has to always work, since the loop body is assigning a locally allocated const string reference to each element (also a string, but not a constant string) within the container.  An iterator type is never attempted to be assigned to the string reference inside the second for loop body.

This new *range for* has many nice features to reduce keyboard typing as much as possible.  However, it is probably best to use the auto keyword and subsequent datatype assignments that the compiler will always get right (assuming it remains in C++11 compliance forever).

The assertion failure of

```
T &t = v.back(); // assertion failure
```

is also completely correct for an empty vector **(Start Edit)**.

The back() method is a recent addition to the STL for me.  I am sorry.  In my haste to complete the original post before heading out, I read the word back() and translated that in my brain to end().

If the end() method is called: The T &t is not the same type as `std :: vector<T> :: iterator`, which is what is returned when v.end() is called.  In terms of types it looks more like this:

```
 T &t = std::vector<T> :: iterator
```

After reviewing the details on std::vector::back(), if back() is called on an empty vector, the behavior is *undefined*.  More than likely, finding the flaw would be only at run time.  For reference, try this: http://www.cpluscplus.com/reference/vector/vector/back.  For always calling back(), the first thing that has to be confirmed is that at least one element exists inside the vector.  Prior to that, since `emplace_back(Args&&... args);` is the prototype at http://www.cpluscplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace_back, calling it with no parameter to insert after the current last element is not defined.  The reference page says, "If allocator_traits::construct is not supported with the appropriate arguments, it causes *undefined behavior*."  The code will probably have to become something more like:

```
//
// start of the 'earlier' function body 
//
std::string s;
v.emplace_back(s); // add one element to v

//
// obtain a reference to the last element (should be a copy of s above)
//
T &t = v.back(); 



//
// It is not clear what the vector 'to' is and how it exists inside 'earlier'
// as long as 'to' has at least one element, then the code below will 
// set the local reference variable to the last element of 'to'.  
// If not, then another run time error is likely with attempting to access to[-1]
// and then attempting to assign the non-existent element to T& val
//
T &val = to[to.size() - 1];
```

I hope this helps understand the difference between an iterator, adding an element after the current last element, and the data element type stored inside a container.

**(End Edit)**

It would be very surprising that the memory assignment area is a problem.  Visual Studio 2012 would have a host of unhappy C++ engineers.  It is highly recommended to undo whatever modifications occurred inside the stl source code.

Comment: `vector.back()` returns a `T`, not an iterator.

Comment: Updated to correctly discuss back(), end() and alternative for the 'earlier' function body.

Comment: Before the back call, the vector was not empty. The emplace_back call inserted an element.

Comment: Regarding the iterator, if the assignment were incompatible, I would expect a type-checking error. Also I tried auto, it failed. The problem was as described below. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @Tim The v.emplace_back() call cannot possibly add an element.  Not providing the "what to add" after the current last element is *undefined*, even though syntactically allowed.  The intent to have at least one element added to an empty vector is equivalent to using v.push_back(std::string s) and/or v.insert(v.end(), std::string s). The big difference is emplace_back(Args&&... args) is variadic. Hence, the possibility exists for confusing the C++11 allowance of zero arguments for a variadic argument list, with the reality that emplace_back has undefined behavior if nothing is passed.

Comment: @Tim Please show exactly how auto has been used when it failed.  Did using auto fail as a compile time error or run time?  Is the failure before or after the modification within the vector setup code depths?  Regarding the *range for* iterator assignment issue not being caught by the compiler, that is a question for the Visual Studio compiler designers.  To me, any time one type is attempted to be assigned to a different type, the compiler should complain.  If not, then perhaps -Wall or -Weverything should be enabled.  I do not know what these options are called in Visual Studio though.

Comment: @CPlusPlusOOAandD This question is not a spec. issue, but an implementation one.  We found the problem and know what's going on.  However, your comments about undefined behavior are always welcome (see below). :-)

Comment: @CPlusPlusOOAandD The emplace_back() call with no arguments adds an element by calling the no-arg (default) constructor (in-place on the new element).  When I first saw the problem days ago, my first inclination was to actually try push_back(T()) instead, and it's semantically equivalent (given T's type).  If this is some non-portable use of emplace_back, then I am unaware of it.  A link would be welcome here (all my references on that method are vague about the no-args version).

Comment: @CPlusPlusOOAandD To see auto type fail, change the type annotation from const std::string to auto with or without reference type (it blows up before any assignment anyways); and it fails for exactly the same reason: the underlying container proxy got zeroed out by the memset.

Comment: @Tim The web site link to undefined behavior and respective quote from the reference are already above.

Comment: @Tim On the use of memset for a vector, or any other container, it is not recommended.  It is expected that will have undefined and unpredictable results, since the container iterators and other container internals will be negatively affected in a big way (more below).

Comment: @Tim When first learning the STL in 1996, that is not how any book described how to set a container of elements to initial values.  If a vector were exactly like a C array, then memset would work.  However, that is not the case.  The best, shortest way to set STL container elements to initial values, that may differ from the element's default, is to purposely create a local single element instance (e.g. a std::string set to "NOTHING HERE YET"), and then inserting the local for the whole container, element by element.  The for-range and/or traditional for loop will be handy.