# vector iterators incompatible when deep copying vectors

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am running into this "vector iterators incompatible" assert and I have no idea why. I looked at few answers here but none of them helped. I wonder if anyone can spot the issue. It is basically a vector that I am deep copying, but when I iterate through the copy, it asserts. Code is a bit confusing, but I could not re-pro with a simpler case:

```
#include <vector>    
class MyClass
{
 public:
MyClass() {};
~MyClass() {};
virtual MyClass* Clone()
{
    MyClass* clone = new MyClass(*this);
    return clone;
}
int GetData() const { return m_data; }
 private:
int     m_data;

};

typedef std::vector<MyClass*> MyClassList;

struct MyStruct
{
    MyClassList myClassList;
};
struct MyStruct2
{
    MyStruct2() {};
    MyStruct *pData2;
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MyClassList* m_pMyClasssOrig;
    m_pMyClasssOrig = new MyClassList();
    m_pMyClasssOrig->push_back(new MyClass());
    m_pMyClasssOrig->push_back(new MyClass());
    m_pMyClasssOrig->push_back(new MyClass());

    // Setup worker parameters
    MyStruct2*        pWorkerParam  = new MyStruct2();
    MyStruct*        pData2         = new MyStruct();

    memset(pWorkerParam, 0x00, sizeof(MyStruct2));
    memset(pData2, 0x00, sizeof(MyStruct));
    pWorkerParam->pData2 = pData2;

    // Make deep copy of the myClassList
    for (auto pMyClass : *m_pMyClasssOrig)
    {
        auto decoderCopy = pMyClass->Clone();
        pWorkerParam->pData2->myClassList.push_back(decoderCopy);
    }
    // why do I get "Expression: vector iterators incompatible"
    // here?
    for (auto i = pWorkerParam->pData2->myClassList.begin(); i !=  pWorkerParam->pData2->myClassList.end(); i++)
    {
        MyClass*    pMyClass = *i;
       (void)pMyClass->GetData();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See the [documentation of `std::memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset). Unless your object type is [*trivially copyable*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable) (and `MyStruct` is *not*, as its `std::vector<>` is not), the resulting behavior of your code is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `memset` on a `std::vector`.

You don't know what `std::vector`'s internals are, so you should not be zeroing them out. If you need to clear the vector, then use the `clear` method.

Even for your class that just has a pointer in it, don't use memset, make the constructor set the pointer to NULL.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the `memset` is stomping on internal vector state.  Try removing that and see if it passes.  I ran into this exact problem.  [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923800/c-for-each-statement-triggers-vector-iterators-incompatible-assertion-failur).  The accepted answer explains.